# Unable to download ANSICON after installing Cucumber in Windows7 64bit

Tags: ruby, cucumber, ansicon, ruby-development-kit

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

1. I have installed Ruby1.9.3 and Ruby DevKit 4.5.2 successfully
2. I have installed Cucumber by using the following command:

   gem install cucumber
3. Cucumber was installed that was confirmed by using cucumber --help command
4. Now is the time to install ANSICON. I tried to download ANSICON from http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/

When I visit the site: http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/  the following message was shown in the browser:

Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from adoxa.3eeweb.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

How can I download and install ANSICON?

Comment: You could try downloading from the github page: https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads

Comment: OK orde, I shall try on this to download. thanks

Comment: @orde: Thanks. I have downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below for ANSICON installation in Windows7 64-bit:

1. Download and unzip the latest version from https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads
2. Open a command prompt and cd to the folder where you unzipped it. Now, cd into either x86 or x64 (depending on your machine’s processor) and install it by executing the following command:

   C:\somewhere\ansi160\x64> ansicon -i

Any program that prints ANSI colors will now display properly on your machine after successful installation of ANSICON.